# Push Notifications for Windows 10 UWP hybrid mobile app

Tags: windows, push-notification, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a hybrid mobile app built using Angular + Ionic, packaged with Cordova.  Supports Windows 10, iOS and Andriod; Looking to have the push notification added, so have used firebase for iOS and Android.

Reading thro a lot of documentation on Microsoft and forums, I am not very clear on how will the push notifications work on Windows 10 app. So have a few questions listed:

1. Anybody tried using firebase for windows 10 - will it work?
2. Any Windows cordova plugins available to get push to work on windows 10 hybrid mobile app?
3. Will Push notifications on Windows 10 still work if my app is not hosted on Microsoft/Windows store? I have no plans of hosting there
4. Can anybody point me to the latest URL's on adding push notif support for win 10 hybrid cordova app; The pages I saw on Microsoft site seems to be very old 2015 etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Anybody tried using firebase for windows 10 - will it work?

Firebase only supports IOS/Android.

> Any Windows cordova plugins available to get push to work on windows 10 hybrid mobile app?

Please see [Windows Plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/windows/plugin.html) for details.

> Will Push notifications on Windows 10 still work if my app is not hosted on Microsoft/Windows store? I have no plans of hosting there

Yes. But you would need to register your app in window [dashboard](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows). Because if you want to push notification, the Package Security Identifier (SID) and a secret key are reqired. You will get them after you register your app in dashboard.

> Can anybody point me to the latest URL's on adding push notif support for win 10 hybrid cordova app; The pages I saw on Microsoft site seems to be very old 2015 etc

There's only Plugins document. You could follow the steps on the original [WNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview) document to add the push notif support by yourself.

Comment: Thanks Xavier, will give it a try

Comment: I am also looking for this, and noticed OneSignal, while no "direct" support, does say it is possible. See [here for some details](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/windows-app-sdk-setup). I Haven't tried it myself yet. Perhaps a similar thing could be used with Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Answer as of Q1 2023:

You can use Azure [Notifications Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/products/notification-hubs/), to send push notifications to devices of various platforms in a scalable manner. Main advantage is that you do *not* need to send message to each individual PNS(push notification service) example APNS, Firebase etc.

Even for apps that run on Windows, either UWP or the newer MAUI platform based, can receive push notifications via Azure NH.[NH sends to WNS, and it would deliver the actual message].